# How to pull data from two tables?

Tags: sql, select, insert, inner-join

Consider a case where I have :

```
CREATE TABLE COMMANDE(
   _ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
   login_id INTEGER NOT NULL 
   menu_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
   FOREIGN KEY(login_id) REFERENCES LOGIN(_ID),
   FOREIGN KEY(menu_id) REFERENCES MENU(_ID)
)
```

For this table I can do :

// First Order

```
INSERT INTO COMMANDE VALUES (0, 0, 0);
```

// Second Order :

```
INSERT INTO COMMANDE VALUES (1, 0, 0);
```

// Third Order : Different User

```
INSERT INTO COMMANDE VALUES (2, 1, 0);
```

// Fouth Order : Different Menu Item

```
INSERT INTO COMMANDE VALUES (3, 1, 1);
```

How can I get the details of a specific user ? Or the details of a specific item ? with a `SELECT` query since these tables are linked with a constraint ...

Can it be done ? Maybe with some `INNER JOIN` ?

Comment: [1] The DDL is not well formed [2] You do NOT insert autoincrement columns values [4] FK column values are not 0 generally [3] No constraint stops you from getting data for a coumn value - select * from commande where login_id = <some_integer>

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM COMMANDE C
LEFT JOIN LOGIN L ON (C.login_id = L._id)
LEFT JOIN MENU M ON (C.menu_id = M._id)
WHERE C.login_id = 1
```

Something like this?

Comment: You don't need `LEFT JOIN`. These are foreign keys, so matching rows are required to exist in the referenced tables.

Answer (score 0):

To get details of a specific user:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM LOGIN l
JOIN COMMANDE c ON l._id = c.login_id
JOIN MENU m ON m._id = c.menu_id
WHERE l._id = 1
```